# Рекурсивный рендер с выполнением функции, если она дочерний компонент React

Tags: reactjs

Есть компонент (содержимое Card набросано для провеки):

```
<Card list={objs}>
    <div key={obj => obj.id}>
        <div id={obj => obj.id}>
            <span>({obj => obj.id})</span>
            <span>{obj => obj.name}</span>
        </div>
   </div>
</Card>
```

Необходимо сымитировать работу `map`, но сам компонент должен реализовываться как описано выше. Ожидаемый результат (или типо того, тут не принципиально, он должен будет рендериться по шаблону внутри Card):

```html
<div>
    <div class="card">
        <div id="1">
            <span>(1)</span>
            <span>Ivan</span>
        </div>
   </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div id="2">
            <span>(2)</span>
            <span>Ivan</span>
        </div>
   </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div id="3">
            <span>(3)</span>
            <span>John</span>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Что пробывал я:

```
const Card = (props) => {

    const children = props.children;

    const render_components = (root, obj) => {
        return (
            Array.isArray(root)
            ?
                root.map(
                    el => render_components(el.props.children)
                    )
            :
                (
                    typeof root.props
                    ?
                        render_components(root.props.children)
                    :
                        typeof root === "function"
                        ?
                            root(obj)
                        :
                            root
                    )
            )

    }

    return (
        <>
        {
            props.list.map(obj => (
                render_components(children, obj)
                )
            )
        }
        </>
    );
};
```

И разные вариации условий. В основном получаю ошибку: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined`, ну и о том, что функция не может быть дочерним компонентом реакт, что мне и не нужно, нужен её результат выполнения (в функцию передаётся obj, что есть текущий элемент из objs и получается объект должен стать доступен в children).

UPD:
Изменил render_components и теперь оно либо рендерит данные из функций либо (если убрать проверку на наличие пропсов), рендерит структуру, но не данные:

```js
const render_components = (root, obj) => {
        if (Array.isArray(root)) return root.map(el => render_components(el, obj));
        else if (root.props) return render_components(root.props.children, obj);
        else if (typeof root === "function") return root(obj);
        else return root;
    }
```

И я, в принципе, понял почему - без проверки, но рендерит `el` целиком со всем, что внутри, вроде так...

Comment: Сложно понять вопрос

Comment: @KonstantinModin, нужно скрыть `map'ы` и сделать реализацию структуры компонента в `children'е`, чтобы структура развернулась из кода 1 в код 2 (хотя бы примерно) на основе данных в пропе `list`. Примерно как в vue'шной директиве v-for/v-in, но только в реакте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного изменив структуру дочерних эл-тов компонента получилось добиться нужного эффекта. Помогла вот эта статься: https://codedaily.io/tutorials/Using-Functions-as-Children-and-Render-Props-in-React-Components